# i made a testing class in laravel and using factory in it to make a user but it is giving error that "fname" doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-testing

```
public function test_case1()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create([
        'fname' => "Testing",
        'lname' => 'bot',
        'email'    => "testing_bot@apimio.com",
        'password' => bcrypt("testing_bot"),
    ]);
    $this->assertTrue($user->is_subscribed());
}
```

this code is giving error
General error: 1364 Field 'fname' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2022-01-31 08:44:43, 2022-01-31 08:44:43))
when i run test
NOTE:: This code is working fine on my teammate's pc but not on mine and i dont know why :(

Comment: Please include your user factory.

Comment: it was composer related issue which is solved now, thanks for the reply btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the `User` model for something along the name of `$fillable` this should be an array of values that are mass assignable for the purposes of factories.

Then you have to include the one's in your example.

Comment: alright!  thanks for the help